# Pandas Dataframe images and links are removed with the .tohtml() function

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe named df. In this dataframe every row has an image and then a link to an article. When I use the df.tohtml() function the html code that i get does not generate an img tag for the picture but only gives me the href link of the image. Also the link is just plain text and not a hyperlink.

Comment: Can you add your code as an example? You've followed the doc right? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.